# using pandas dataframe compare one column value with other list of elements in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

using pandas compare two columns and create a new column if both columns match the same string else assign any value from a list of elements

[image]

Comment: Can you explain the output of your two last rows please?

Comment: from what i see: if single fruit is in multiple fruits then output=single fruit ||
if single fruit is not in multiple fruits then output  = one random fruit which is in multiples fruit

Comment: hey @Corralien  if single_fruit col value is not matched with multiple_fruits col value the output should be pick from multiple_fruits col value either any of element from it

Comment: @Raklet57 absolutely you are correct it should pick like that

Comment: any help @Corralien from your end

Comment: any help @Raklet57 from your end as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if `single fruit` is in `multiple fruits` then return `single fruit` else choose a random fruit in `multiple fruits`:

```
import numpy as np

df['output'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['single fruit'] 
                          if x['single fruit'] in x['multiple fruits']
                          else np.random.choice(x['multiple fruits']), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  single fruit              multiple fruits      output
0        apple               [apple, mango]       apple
1       grapes                     [grapes]      grapes
2   strawberry  [strawberry, grapes, mango]  strawberry
3    pineapple               [apple, mango]       apple
4        graps          [strawberry, mango]  strawberry
```

Comment: excellent working thanks for help